# Connecting SQL Server Imbedded app in Linux

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-5

Thanks for checking my issue, Recently I developed a simple application with **c#, .Net 5** that connects to the SQL server database which is deployed on Windows Server, I tried to run the application and it works perfectly fine and connects with the database with no error. but when i deploy the app in Linux, it is throwing an error that says connection that says "Network Error or Instance related..."
I've used the following code as a connection string: `"Server=tcp:telda.com.et,1433;initial catalog=Database;user id=username;password=password;"` Do i need to install something on the linux machine to make it work?? Note that with the following connection string, the application works perfectly fine on the Windows client

Comment: Is the Linux machine on the same network as the windows client? Is it using the same DNS?

Comment: no, it is not on the same network but i am using the exact code to connect, it is even in a different region. is there anything i need to enable on the client machine (Linux)

Comment: If the linux machine cannot access that network then you have a networking issue, not a code issue. I can't help with that.

Comment: If you can't connect using `telnet telda.com.et 1433` then you won't be able to connect with other programs either. Check the configurations of software and network firewalls along the way. On the machine that was connecting successfully check the hosts file (on Windows, `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to see if there is a hard-coded IP address lookup for that domain name, as well as potential Client Alias configurations in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried that too but no issues with that... i tried to disable the firwall and also allow port to connect to telnet, but that didn't help, i couldn't connect using telnet outside the VPS but it allows me to connect using a loopback ie: `telnet localhost` but not with the public ip outside the VPS. maybe the VPS service providers made some policy... i really dont understand the issue.